# ubuntu 16.04. ssh host certificate revocation

Tags: ssh, authentication, certificate

This question regards configuration of SSH on client host side
when a server HOST certificate is known to be compromised.

In brief:
How do we revoke SSH HOST certificates, what files need to be
updated on CLIENT side hosts so that the certificate offered
by the responding server during ssh connection attempt is
recognised as a revoked certificate?

The long version:
CLIENT certificates:

Each user generates a key pair, submits the public key to a CLIENT
CA who generates a client certificate and returns it to the user.
The user puts the certificate (ending in -cert.pub) alongside his
private key and it gets loaded by ssh-add when he adds the private
key and supplies the passphrase.

The CLIENT CA's public key is listed in the server hosts' trusted CAs file
and the sshd daemon authorises the user's connection because the CA
appears in that file.  It also  checks other conditions specified the certificate such as not expired and  account in user principals.
The server also checks whether the certificate has been revoked against
the revoked user's file.
So when the user's private key and certificate have been compromised,
as soon as the CA is notified, he revokes the certificate and
distributes that to server host revoked users files.

Consequently the compromised key and certificate are no longer a threat
when the revoked users files have been updated.

HOST certificates:

Each host node has a host certificate which has been signed by a HOST CA.
Each client node has global known hosts file typically /etc/ssh_known_hosts which has been updated to contain an entry for the given HOST CA.  But there appears to be no revoked hosts file anywhere.

When a user on the client node attempts to ssh into the server
host, ssh (on the client host) accepts the host certificate
offered by the server host because the public key of the
signing authority who signed that certificate is in the
ssh_known_hosts file.
But where and when is that host certificate
verified against revocation? The revoked users file on hosts
applies to client certificates regarding INCOMING connections.
HOST certificates need to be checked by SSH on OUTGOING connections
to server hosts, the certificate offered needs to be checked for
revocation by SSH on the client side.   If that were not done, the ONLY
way to recover from a compromised host key and certificate would be
for the CA itself to become untrusted, to be removed from /etc/ssh_known_hosts on the client host system.  T
his would mean all hosts with certificates signed by the same CA would also be rendered unknown hosts.

So what and where do we put revoked HOST information on client host side
so that ssh recognises host certificates as revoked and identifies
the HOST  as untrustworthy?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Ask CA to revoke the certificate and update CRL. Clients will automatically download CRL during connection and will be noticed that server certificate is revoked by its issuer.

Comment: @Crypt32: _OpenSSH_ certs are _not_ the X.509/PKIX certs used in SSL/TLS and S/MIME etc, normally do not use external CA(s), and never use CRLs, although as the self-answer says they do have KRLs which are conceptually similar (but not automatic)

Answer (score 2):

openssh specifies a configuration option for this.

Add the following line to **/etc/ssh/ssh_config**:

**RevokedHostKeys** /etc/ssh/revoked_host_keys

That file must exist and be readable otherwise all host keys
will be rejected. The file can either contain a public key per line for each revoked host key. Or it can be a KRL file which is a more compact.

ssh-keygen can produce a KRL file from such a text file.

See man ssh-keygen and man ssh_config for more information.

Blush.. I'm answering my own question.
Sorry for bothering everyone I had looked everywhere for an answer to my question, yet only found my answer after posting the question.

Comment: It is fine that you answer your own question. Other people might have the same question and now the answer is here. You should also accept the answer so that it is known to be valid.